# search parameter in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

user.js

```
exports.getProducts = async (name, brand) => {
 let queryFilters = { name , brand }   // ====>>> if brand or name is = '' then it not search
 queryFilters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryFilters));
 let userRecords = await model.find( queryFilters).exec();
 return userRecords
};
```

name and brand are query parameters and I want if name or brand is blank or undefined it does not pass in query parameter like localhost:3001/product?name=dj&brand= in this case it only search for name=dj not brand as it searches for name=dj and brand='' same if brand is given and name is undefined or blank. I also want like in SQL for e.g. if the name is dj and if I search for d then it also search for dj.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
let queryFilters = {};

if(name != ''){
    queryFilters.name = name
};

if(brand != ''){
    queryFilters.brand = brand
};
```

if name or brand has value it will assign otherwise it will not include this fields.

Comment: I have done it earlier but don't want this because if i have 9 to 10 fields then it will become messy

Comment: It is best way for this case.  it is not good to have 9,10 parameters in the function. Instead if you have an array as a parameter then the question changes and yes also answer will be different.

Comment: Yes i can have array as a parameter instead of different parameters. Can you please help me out if it name amd brand would be in array

Comment: I used object as a parameter, check this example. 

function getProducts(obj) {
  let queryFilters = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj[key]) {
      queryFilters[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }

  console.log(queryFilters);
}

getProducts({
  a: "value_1",
  b: null,
  c: "value_2"
});